# jQuery mousemove() is called even if the mouse is still

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, mousemove

For me, if I try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bY3CC/3/ the "mouse moved" text appears even if I move my mouse over the document and then I let it still...

Why's that? ;\

And also, seems like the message only appears in Chrome....

Strange :-s

Comment: probably related to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17819113/2464167

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global `event` object is non-standard, so it only exists in some browsers, like IE (perhaps only in quirks mode) and appearently in Chrome.

Accept the event object as a parameter to the event handler:

```
var last_moved=0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var now = e.timeStamp;    
  if (now - last_moved > 1000) {
    $('#messages').append('mouse moved<br/>');
    last_moved = now;
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/bY3CC/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/bY3CC/5/)

Comment: Ok, that solved half of the problem. Now, why's the message appearing if if the mouse is still?

Comment: I don't have Chrome installed right now, but I have tested this in Firefox 3, IE 9, Opera 11 and Safari 4, and they don't trigger the event when the mouse is still. Perhaps Chrome does something odd, or perhaps you have some plugin or something that could cause this?

Comment: It also happens on my Chrome installation (9.0.597.19 beta). Oddly, printing the current mouse pixel position shows it's always at the same position.

Comment: This is odd, after restarting Chrome, it worked perfectly... Here is what I was working at anyway :D  http://bit.ly/hRpiqr

Comment: @Guffa why when you click on the document it shows the message too? the mouse still at the same position?

Comment: @msm.oliveira: Because you are actually moving the mouse a little bit when clicking. It's possible to click without moving the mouse at all, but it's not easy. Note that a mouse movement may be too small to move the mouse pointer a pixel, but it's still registered as a movement.

Answer (score 11):

Store the x, y co-ordinates

```
$(document).mousemove((function(){
    var x,y;

    return function(evt){
        if(evt.clientX == x && evt.clientY == y){
            return;
        }
        x = evt.clientX;
        y = evt.clientY;
        $('#messages').append('mouse moved<br/>');
    };
})());
```